# Replace pattern at end of a string by pattern at the beginning

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm very new to regular expressions, so my apologies if this is an obviously stupid question.

Suppose I have a string of the form (c"fair*", "beaut*") and I want to replace the asterisk (*) at the end by a caret (^) at the beginning: c("^fair", "^beaut"). How could I go about doing that using stringr? I have read [this excellent introduction to regexp](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html), but did not figure it out. I made several attempts with stringr::str_replace_all(), to no avail. The issue seems to be that the replacement in stringr::str_replace_all() can't be a regexp. Is that so? If yes, is there any other way to do this?

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("fair*", "beaut*")
str_replace_all(x, "\\*", "^\\^")
#> [1] "fair^^"  "beaut^^"
str_replace_all(x, "\\*", "^\\^")
#> [1] "fair^^"  "beaut^^"
str_replace_all(x, "\\*", "\\^*")
#> [1] "fair^*"  "beaut^*"
str_replace_all(x, "\\*", "\\^(*)")
#> [1] "fair^(*)"  "beaut^(*)"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
x <- c("fair*", "beaut*")
str_replace(x, "(.*)\\*$", "^\\1")
# => [1] "^fair"  "^beaut"
sub("(.*)\\*$", "^\\1", x)
# => [1] "^fair"  "^beaut"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0jtpr/1) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/EgBG6A). Note that `str_replace` will be enough as there is only one substitution that can occur here. That is why I also suggest `sub` rather than `gsub` as a base R counterpart.

The `(.*)\*$` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars (other than line break chars) as many as possible, then just matches a literal `*` asterisk char (`\*`) at the end of string (`$`).

The `^\1` replacement pattern replaces the match with `^` and the value of Group 1.

**NOTE**: If your strings contain line breaks, the `stringr` solution will need a slight fix: `str_replace(x, "(?s)(.*)\\*$", "^\\1")`.

Comment: @KarstenW. Sure, just the question was *How could I go about doing that using stringr?*

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to the fact that I can use stringr::str_replace(), rather than stringr::str_replace_all()

Answer (score 2):

This one could also help:

```
sub("(^[[:alpha:]]+)\\*$", "^\\1", x, perl = TRUE)

[1] "^fair"  "^beaut"
```

Comment: You do not need to escape `^` in the replacement pattern. It is not a regex.